# Upload image on firebase storage not working android 8.1

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload file on firebase storage. I am able to upload them on any other android version except android 8.1.

```
 ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                       
                        Log.e("DOwnload URi", it.toString())
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e -> // Error, Image not uploaded
//                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                    Toast
                        .makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "Failed " + e.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                        .show()
                }
                .addOnProgressListener { taskSnapshot ->

                    // Progress Listener for loading
                    // percentage on the dialog box
                    val progress = (100.0
                            * taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred
                            / taskSnapshot.totalByteCount)
//                    progressDialog.setMessage(
//                        "Uploaded "
//                                + progress.toInt() + "%"
//                    )
                }
                .addOnCanceledListener {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
```

None of the listeners is working as well. Just nothing happens.

Comment: "None of the listeners is working as well" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).